# I need to find the users list on a linux server who have a file named 'html_public' but without using grep,sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell

the users are in a directory called '/home/scs' ,here's what I've got

```
[trgi3709@linux ~]$ find /home/scs html_public | cut -d/ -f6
```

I'll use it in a shell script, just testing over there, but this way there are rows where the 6th field doesn't contain the name of the user, and I only need the name, if I give any other option it'll give me something that I don't need, so any idea how can I find only the user who got the file 'html_public' inside '/home/scs'  without using grep , sed  or awk

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `find /home/scs -name html_public`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use printf and %u and so:

```
find /home/scs html_public -printf "%f %u\n"
```

%f will print the file name and %u the name of the user who owns the file

Comment: thank you,still some problems with the files I don't have permission for, it appears something like that

find: `/home/scs/licenta/an3/gr235/tair2413': Permission denied
nair2574 nair2574
find: `/home/scs/licenta/an3/gr235/nair2574': Permission denied
nair2570 nair2570
find: `/home/scs/licenta/an3/gr235/nair2570': Permission denied
ctir2077 ctir2077
find: `/home/scs/licenta/an3/gr235/ctir2077': Permission denied
ndir2578 ndir2578
how can I make the find row do not appear? Because I'll save the users in an array